# How to use markerOptions in fragment to get MyLocation using LatLng() Method

Tags: android, maps, fragment

I am working on app where i have to show no of Marker on map.I have inflate map through fragment and now want to get my location by using `markerOptions()`.but that show the GoogleMap `null`.

```
public class MapFineTech extends Fragment {
GoogleMap googleMap;
 double getlatitude,getlongitude;
 String latitude_mString,longitude_mString;
 MapView mapView;
 ViewGroup container;
 Fragment fragment;
 GPSTracker gps;
 MarkerOptions marker;


 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fine_tech, container,  false);
 fragment =  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

 Log.d("u r", "ur in register device");
new Thread(null,registerDeviceThread,"").start();
gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
 if(gps.canGetLocation()){

     getlatitude = gps.getLatitude();
     getlongitude = gps.getLongitude();
     latitude_mString = String.valueOf(getlatitude);
     longitude_mString = String.valueOf(getlongitude);
     Log.d("Value of lat and long",  latitude_mString+""+longitude_mString);
     Log.d("u r", "ur in register lati loni");
        new Thread(null,latlongThread,"").start();

}else{

    gps.showSettingsAlert();
}
 Log.d("Value of lat and long",  latitude_mString+""+longitude_mString);

 marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(getlatitude,    getlongitude));
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
 marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.applogo));

 return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{

        if (fragment != null) {

             fragment =  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
               FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               ft.remove(fragment);
               ft.commit();
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         Thread.interrupted();
    super.onPause();
  }
```

By this code map can be shown but the app crasher due to googleMap is null,when i add addMarker to googleMap.

Comment: Add this line, in onCreateView(): `googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)) .getMap();` or just do `googleMap = ((MapFragment) fragment).getMap()` after creating your fragment

Comment: this is not working ...showing MapFragment cannot resolved to a type @Rami

Comment: try to import  `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`

Comment: You are welcome, i added the answer for future users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to this question:

import

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

and edit

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fine_tech, container,  false);
     fragment =  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
     googleMap = ((MapFragment) fragment).getMap(); // this is the edit

     ......// the rest of the code

    }
```